# PDF JS : PDF not loading in IE browser

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

The below code works fine in Chrome but, not in Internet Explorer, I have tried adding compatibility.js but no luck. It does not render in IE at all.

I need some suggestions on this and I have gone through every solution out there and I could not make it work.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script src="https://go.qlik.com/rs/497-BMK-910/images/compatibility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = document.querySelector('a#get_pdf').href;
    var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

    var pdfDoc = null,
        pageNum = 1,
        pageRendering = false,
        pageNumPending = null,
        scale = 1,
        canvas = document.getElementById('pdf-attach'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function renderPage(num) {
        pageRendering = true;
        pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
            var viewport = page.getViewport({
                scale: scale
            });
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;
            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: ctx,
                viewport: viewport
            };
            var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function() {
                pageRendering = false;
                if (pageNumPending !== null) {
                    renderPage(pageNumPending);
                    pageNumPending = null;
                }
            });
        });
        document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
    }
    function queueRenderPage(num) {
        if (pageRendering) {
            pageNumPending = num;
        } else {
            renderPage(num);
        }
    }
    function onPrevPage() {
        if (pageNum <= 1) {
            return;
        }
        pageNum--;
        queueRenderPage(pageNum);
    }
    document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);
    function onNextPage() {
        if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
            return;
        }
        pageNum++;
        queueRenderPage(pageNum);
    }
    document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);
    pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
        pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
        document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
        renderPage(pageNum);
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Could you expand on what "doesn't work" means in this case? Does it not render at all? Does it render badly? What version of IE are you targetting? Is it worth it now that IE is (nearly) dead?

Comment: Sorry.. yes PDF does not render at all.

Comment: What version of IE are you targetting?

Comment: You could detect IE and force it to download the PDF (treat the file as an attachment) rather than to try to display it inline. The user would then use their locally installed PDF reader to read the PDF.

Comment: IE 8 and above. Yes as you said above we can do. But as per PDF.js it is working in IE.
This is their demo URL : https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/web/viewer.html

Comment: I don't think you should support anything under IE11 - you're bending over backwards to support technology that no-one should be using any more (and that is well out of support/security updates). However, if the demo works for that version, have a look at the response headers on the demo - maybe by including them in your own work you can get IE to work too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make it work. It must be the build for ES5-compatible.

change

`https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js` into `https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/build/pdf.js`

And

`//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js` into
`//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/es5/build/pdf.worker.js`

Update for `IE Edge`:

```
tags v2.5.207 works
tags v2.6.347 failed to render some letters
```